# Processing buffers bigger than 65536 in Clyther/OpenCL

Tags: python, opencl

I am currently in the process of discovering OpenCL via the Python binding Clyther. So
far I am messing with a very simple script to get the sin or cos of a buffer of 65536. 
Apparently 65536 is the limit for buffers on my card but say I'd have 16 million numbers in my buffer how would I go about it without constantly bringing the CPU into it to retrieve/send data?

What I have do so far is, fill buffer, run kernel, retrieve buffer, in a loop but that also
hits the CPU badly.

I looked a bit at OpenCL docs but I just failed to understand how that is achieved.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awfully looks like you are using `__constant` memory. The solution is to use `__global` memory instead, but you have to be careful about how you access it for best performance.

`__constant` memory is a special address space for often used constant values, but is restricted in size on current GPUs.